# Cast ASP Repeater DataSource to C# List

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater called rptFoo and C# `List<String>` called listFoo.
I only know that I can assign a List as repeater `DataSource`, like this:

```
rptFoo.DataSource = listFoo
rptFoo.DataBind();
```

This repeater is rendered to Textbox, then I make some change on the textbox's text. 
Can I get the list vice versa? I mean, when **data changed on some textbox** at my repeater item, can I assign it to my C# list, like this:

```
listFoo = DataSource
```

I'm looking for something better than accessing the repeater item one by one via `foreach`.
Any idea?

This is the way I do:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptFoo.Items)
{
  TextBox myTextBox= (TextBox)item.FindControl("myTextBox");
  listFoo[item.ItemIndex] = myTextBox.Text;
}
```

I want to get any edited data on my repeater to be reflect on my list to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the need for this type of code?Have you made some changes in rptFoo data ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible because repeater's datasource is null after postback, ofcourse you can cast DataSource at the same roundtrip, but that would not be useful because nothing have changed.
The correct approach I believe is to attach to events which truly change your data and modify your list appropriately.

Comment: Oh yup, I forgot to tell that I've made some change on my Repeater Item

Comment: I think that if you change something automatically this is reflected to your list (and not need to make listFoo=datasource - please check it out.

Comment: @Aristos This doesn't happen. DataBinding is a one-way road: you can't simply pull out a list from the repeater, and it certainly doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Yup, my repeater is rendered as Textbox. @Aristos: I've tried it, but the data is not reflected, my repeater is rendered as Textbox, and I changed the textbox's text

Comment: Can you post some code on how you plan to use this? There is most probably a much better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Your code is good enough, thats a standard approach.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1233362.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

A better way than looping through each repeater item and finding the textbox is probably to utilise the TextBox control's **OnTextChanged** event handler.  This will give you direct access to the TextBox object and it's new value.